# Bootstrap 3 Navbar does not collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know there is something simple I am missing, but when I shrink my screen, the navbar collapse toggle does not work.  I've already search SO and I cannot find a solution that fixes my issues.

Can someone help me figure out what I am missing in the code below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slate-bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/larry.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
  <header class="container">
    <div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="btn btn-success navbar-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
            </button>
            <div id="logo">
                <h4><a href='./index.html'><img src="images/LE-logo.png"></a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav active"><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="./resume.html">Resume</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="./about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section id="body" class="container">
    <section id="main" class="col-md-9">
        <p> Ipsome loreme, blah , blah</p>

    </section>
  </section>


  <hr />
  <footer class="container">
    <p>Placeholder for footer</p>
  </footer>
</div>

<script scr="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script scr="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The glyphicon shows up, but it sill not toggle the navbar-collapse div.

Comment: What you have is already working fine http://jsfiddle.net/NkED8/

Comment: Thanks @rwisch45. It must be a browser issue or the jquery is not loading for some reason. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll keep working on that.

Comment: I've tried this in JSBin, but it still does not work: http://jsbin.com/ACedUras/1/edit?html,output  
Sorry, but I'm still pretty new to JS and Bootstrap.

Comment: @rwisch45 I found the answer, but if you post an answer, I'll give you the points since your comment got me started in the right direction.  Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging in Firebug (definitely the best browser debug tool out there), I found it was not loading bootstrap.js correctly.  I'm not sure why it wasn't picking it up from my directory, but I changed to the CDN and I had to have the "http://" in front.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok. If the navbar-collapse element never shown, check did you add any style for it, how did you hide it?

Comment: This is part of the Bootstrap framework from what I understand.  You just add specific class names to the div, then wire up the data-toggle and data-target and it should handle this for you.